# Moving items between different lists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm new in JavaScript and currently learning. I want to be able to move the list items between the different to do lists but the thing is it has to be written in native JavaScript. Right now I can only move the items from the first list and only the checked one. Here is my drag and drop code.
[codepen](https://codepen.io/ismet-brahimbashew/pen/eYEELLP)

```js
let list = document.querySelector('.mylist');
let draggedItem;

function isLiItem(event) {
  return event.target && event.target.classList.contains("checked");
}

function onDragStart(event) {
  if (isLiItem(event)) {
    event.target.classList.add('on-drag-start');
    draggedItem = event.target;
    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', event.target.innerHTML);
  }
}

function onDragEnter(event) {
  if (isLiItem(event)) {
    event.target.classList.add('on-drag-enter');
  }
}

function onDragLeave(event) {
  if (isLiItem(event)) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.target.classList.remove('on-drag-enter');
  }
}

function onDragOver(event) {
  if (isLiItem(event)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
  }
}

function onDragDrop(event) {
  if (isLiItem(event)) {
    list.insertBefore(draggedItem, event.target);
    draggedItem.classList.remove('on-drag-start');
    event.target.classList.remove('on-drag-start');
  }
}

function onDragEnd(event) {
  let allItems = list.querySelectorAll('.mylist .checked .unchecked');
  allItems.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove('on-drag-enter'));
  event.target.classList.remove('on-drag-start');
}

list.addEventListener('dragstart', onDragStart);
list.addEventListener('dragover', onDragOver);
list.addEventListener('dragenter', onDragEnter);
list.addEventListener('dragleave', onDragLeave);
list.addEventListener('drop', onDragDrop);
list.addEventListener('dragend', onDragEnd);
```

```html
<div id="tasks">
  <details>
    <summary>Tasks</summary>
    <form class="additem" onsubmit="addItem(this); return false;">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter new task">
      <input type="submit" value="Add New Task">
    </form>

    <ul class="mylist" id="tasks_list">

    </ul>
  </details>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add items to your list, and add more than one list to the code posted here. Currently the code doesn't do much, since there is no code to add items, and there is only one list.

Comment: This is the full link to my code:  [codepen]( https://codepen.io/ismet-brahimbashew/pen/eYEELLP)